# Problemas al inciar MySQL en WAMP server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

[image: ...]

[image: ...]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tal parece la configuración que le doy de usar el puerto 3302 no se toma en cuenta y sigue usando el puerto 3306

Soy nuevo en esto, no se que más descripción dar, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has modificado el puerto en el fichero my.ini?

Comment: Busqué y la configuración se guarda sin problemas, pone 3302 pero sigue sin correr el servicio de sql

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el servicio? Si es así busca todos los ficheros my.ini en el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución :D
Al momento de instalar wamp no se instaló los dll correspondientes, no me avisó de error alguno, el dll ausente era "MSVCP140.dll" lo instalé con una descarga desde
https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=53840
y funcionó luego de instalar el servicio de sql (mi ignorancia me daba a entender que ya estaba instalado desde el momento que seleccione "Sql" en el instalador de wamp)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]